# Hide Multiple Sheets if Value in Column is No (50+Columns/Sheets) Using Loop

Tags: excel, vba, hide

I have a master sheet (Sheet 1) that contains 50+ rows of specific items. I have a sheet corresponding to each item and named as such (ie. item 1 = "Clearing" so sheet 2 is named "Clearing"). I have a drop down menu for each item in Column D that displays "Yes" or "No".

I currently have a basic code that hides Sheets based on if my "Column D" drop down menus for 50+ rows = "No" (ie. Item 1 marked as "No" so sheet 2 is hidden).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If [D2] = "Yes" Then
    Sheets("Clearing").Visible = True
Else
    Sheets("Clearing").Visible = False
End If

If [D3] = "Yes" Then
    Sheets("Grubbing").Visible = True
Else
    Sheets("Grubbing").Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

I want to be able to run this in a loop for all 50+ items by using a range of cells D2:D50+ without having to enter in each sheet name as I've done above. I haven't been able to figure out how to manage this by looking at other's examples.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are the sheet names in Column C?

Comment: Yes the sheet names are in column C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `Worksheet_Change` event you started out with:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(Range("D2"), Range("D2").End(xlDown))

    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Count = 1 Then
            On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
            If Target = "Yes" Then
                Sheets(Target.Offset(, -1).Value).Visible = True
            Else
                Sheets(Target.Offset(, -1).Value).Visible = False
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "The sheet '" & Target.Offset(, -1) & "' does not exist!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data is set up with the sheet name next to column D (or anywhere really, just adjust the script), you can just loop through.

[image]

```
Sub hide_Sheets()
Dim mainWS As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set mainWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = mainWS.Range("C2:C5") ' Change range as needed

Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In rng
    If cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Yes" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cel.Value).Visible = True
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cel.Value).Visible = False
    End If
Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for but I'm receiving the error "Object doesn't support this property or method" for the following line:

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cel.Value).Hidden = True

Comment: @Buzzlastyear `.Hidden`?? Also, do you want a standalone `Sub` or do you want to use the `Worksheet_Change` event?

Comment: @Buzzlastyear - See my edit, that should be `.Visible`.

Comment: @BigBen - Bah, I didn't catch the `Worksheet Change`